# On API responses from engage.ringcentral.com/voice what does "Jwt is missing" refer to?

Tags: ringcentral

I'm calling the following RingCentral API to retrieve the Engage Voice Agent Session Report

```
GET https://engage.ringcentral.com/voice/api/v1/admin/accounts/11/reportsStreaming
X-Auth-Token: {myToken}
```

as shown here:

https://engage-voice-api-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/analytics/reports/agent-session-report/

If I use the `Authorization: Bearer <myToken>` header, I receive the following error:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized

Jwt is missing
```

I'm sending an Auth Token but to be completely transparent I'm using an Auth token generated from portal.vacd.biz/admin login and not an auth token specifically generated using the documentation so that may be the issue. I assume I'm not giving it the correct token as I'm grabbing the token from the network tab of my browser on an RC sync'd Admin.

How can I call this API?

Answer (score 0):

Engage Voice has both new and legacy endpoints for both the API and Admin Console.

The issue here is mixing of current and legacy endpoints where you are getting a token for the legacy system but calling a current API.

Your token and API need to match.

Current URLs include:

- API: https://engage.ringcentral.com/voice/api/v1/...
- UI: https://engage.ringcentral.com/

Legacy URLs include:

- API: https://portal.vacd.biz/api/v1/...
- UI: https://portal.vacd.biz/

Since you are using the legacy system at https://portal.vacd.biz, you should be calling the following URL with the correct auth header:

```
GET https://portal.vacd.biz/api/v1/admin/accounts/11/reportsStreaming
X-Auth-Token: {token}
```

You should only use the new https://engage.ringcentral.com/voice/api/v1/... API endpoints if you are also logging into the app at the new URL: https://engage.ringcentral.com/ .

Read more on current and legacy URLs here:

https://engage-voice-api-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/authentication/